# ReactJS access ReactNode position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```
const backgroundSvgs: ReactNode[] = returnArrayHtmlElements(svgs, 50);

return (<div>
    {backgroundSvgs.map((e) => {
        e.style.x = '50px'  <-- How can I do this?
    })}
</div>);
```

I have variable `backgroundSvgs`, which is of type `ReactNode[]`; how can I access its style before rendering it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use React.Children.map or React.cloneElement.

React.Children.map:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  return React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
    // Modificação dos estilos do componente filho
    const newChild = React.cloneElement(child, { style: { color: 'red' } });
    return newChild;
  });
}
```

React.cloneElement:

```
function MyComponent(props) {
  return React.cloneElement(props.children, { style: { color: 'red' } });
}
```